# Should I use Laravel's Authorization or Zizaco's Entrust?

Tags: authentication, permissions, authorization, laravel-5.1, entrust

Laravel 5.1.11 already has been updated with [Authorization](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authorization). Zizaco's [Entrust](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust) has been around for a while now. Which should we use in authorising users?

Comment: well, it's depend on how you need your application to be. as, Entrust had `role` concept - while so far i see Authorization as a permission-based only. not to mention, Entrust simplify job in saving user role and permission to database.

Answer (score 2):

I use both. I find policies are helpful for limiting user access to models that they "own", while entrust is helpful for defining roles and permissions for users in general. Sometimes I combine the two by returning true for a policy if the user has a certain role.